# How to fix an Observable not assignable to an Observable<AppState<ClassName>>?

Tags: angular, angularjs

While trying to collect data to show on my front-end, i'm stubbling apon this problem.
My Observable is not assignable to my other variable, the type is not the right one and i can't find a way to debug it.
I do not even know if my explanation are correct.
Even when i manually add the error: '' myself, nothing is working.

Here is my error :

```
 Type 'Observable<{ dataState: DataState; appData: { data: { servers: Server[]; }; time: Date; statusCode: number; httpStatus: string; 
reason: string; message: string; devMessage: string; }; error: string; } | { ...; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AppState<Response>>'.

Type '{ dataState: DataState; appData: { data: { servers: Server[]; }; time: Date; statusCode: number; httpStatus: string; reason: string; message: string; devMessage: string; }; error: string; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'AppState<Response>'.

Property 'error' is missing in type '{ dataState: DataState; appData: null; }' but required in type 'AppState<Response>'.ts(2322)
```

Here is the appState :

```
import { DataState } from '../enumeration/dataState';

export interface AppState<X> {
  dataState: DataState;
  appData: X;
  error: string;
}
```

My response model :

```
import {Server} from "../model/Server";

export interface Response {
  time: Date;
  statusCode: number;
  httpStatus: string;
  reason: string;
  message: string;
  devMessage: string;
  data: { servers?: Server[], server?: Server };
}
```

And finally, my nerve breaking source of unlimited sigh :

```
import { ServerService } from './../../../service/server.service';
import { Status } from './../../../enumeration/status.enum';
import { DataState } from './../../../enumeration/dataState';
import { AppState } from './../../../model/appState';
import { Response } from './../../../response/response';
import {
  BehaviorSubject,
  Observable,
  startWith,
  catchError,
  of,
  map,
} from 'rxjs';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-base',
  templateUrl: './server-base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-base.component.css'],
})
export class ServerBaseComponent {
  public stateApp$?: Observable<AppState<Response>> | undefined | null;
  public static readonly DataState = DataState;
  public static readonly Status = Status;
  public filterStatus$?: Observable<string>;
  public isLoading$?: Observable<boolean>;

  private subjectFilter = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Response | null>(null);
  private isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private serverService: ServerService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stateApp$ = this.serverService.getServerList().pipe(
      map(response => {
        this.dataSubject.next(response);
        return {
          dataState: DataState.LOADED,
          appData: {
            ...response,
            data: { servers: response.data?.servers?.reverse() || [] }
          },
          error: '',
        };
      }),
      startWith({ dataState: DataState.LOADING, appData: null }),
      catchError((error: string) => {
        return of({ dataState: DataState.ERROR, error });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i found a solution, i just passed a returning object who is conform to my Response model

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-base',
  templateUrl: './server-base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-base.component.css'],
})
export class ServerBaseComponent {
  public stateApp$: Observable<AppState<Response>> | undefined;
  public static readonly DataState = DataState;
  public static readonly Status = Status;
  public filterStatus$?: Observable<string>;
  public isLoading$?: Observable<boolean>;

  private subjectFilter = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Response | null>(null);
  private isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private serverService: ServerService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stateApp$ = this.serverService.getServerList().pipe(
      map((response) => {
        this.dataSubject.next(response);
        return {
          dataState: DataState.LOADED,
          appData: {
            ...response,
            data: { servers: response.data?.servers?.reverse() || [] },
          },
        };
      }),
      startWith({
        dataState: DataState.LOADING,
        appData: {
          time: new Date(),
          statusCode: 0,
          httpStatus: '',
          reason: '',
          message: '',
          devMessage: '',
          data: { servers: [] },
        },
      }),
      catchError((error: string) => {
        return of({ dataState: DataState.ERROR, error });
      })
    );
  }
}
```